# How to find who ran the update |Delete sql command in MS SQL 2012

Tags: sql-server

I need to find if there is any query to find out who ran delete or update sql command in MS SQL 2012.

Thanks,
Bharat

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have audit running, it might be hard to tell.

If you are looking for something that happened recently, it might be in the [plan table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299669/how-to-see-query-history-in-sql-server-management-studio) ...

Comment: How to enable auditing for specific to update and delete things.

Comment: google it, try it out and then come back with any questions :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use CDC with small [adjustments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869300/sql-server-2008-change-data-capture-who-made-the-change) to monitor who made changes in your data.