# SQL Server 2008 CDC UserName/HostName

Tags: sql-server, cdc

IN CDC, Is there any way by which, we can get information who(user) made changes in table. and by which system (computer name)?

Answer (score 0):

No ([see this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/34082) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/869300/61305)).

You’d need a trigger, and then have to correlate changed rows between CDC and wherever your trigger logs actions. You could add a column to the table to make that easier, but then you’d only know who made the *last* change.

I think it would be a better approach to either add SQL Audit (though I don’t recall how good the functionality was 15 years ago, and whether what you need is supported by your edition) instead of a trigger, or force data changes through a stored procedure, where you can log as part of the action (eg using the OUTPUT clause).

Comment: Thankyou Sir for response , I also do this ----- "You could add a column to the table to make that easier, but then you’d only know who made the last change."                            
But when I delete record from table , I couldn't get actual user name who delete record.  by this i only get last edit/insert user name.....

Comment: Right, you need your delete trigger to log _somewhere else_ because if you’re relying on a column in the row and you delete the row…